# Virtual Path messing up deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to automate a php deployment in azure devops.
In an existing environment the app service has a virtual path pointing to site\wwwroot\public:
[image]

When I deploy, all data is copied to this directory and not, as expected, to site\wwwroot:
[image]
When I create a new app service (where the default value of virtual path is set to site\wwwroot) everything gets deployed to site\wwwroot:
[image]

So my tests indicate, that the deployment is depending on the settings under `Configuration -> Tab 'Path mappings' -> Virtual applications and directories`.
It seems like a bug to me, because wwwroot should always be the root as its name suggest.

If I try to solve this problem by adding a web.config, that does a rewrite it doesn't work, because there are relative dependencies of some sort.

```
<rule name="reroute to /public" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/public/" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="\public\{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

I can see the login page, but I can't neither login nor open any other linked page, because php expect requests to happen @domain.com/call, but the rewrite changes those calls to @domain.com/public/call, so they all fail.

So the only solution seems to be to set the virtual path to site\wwwroot\public for the page to work.
And if I deploy I temporarily change it to site\wwwroot. I don't like this, but it seems to be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer edited after the question modified*

Thanks for these details shared.

According to the first screenshot, you has set your default root path as `site\wwwroot\public`. This means no matter how you deploy to, for all of the applications, its root path always be `site\wwwroot\public`. That's why the your actually deployment path still be `site\wwwroot\public`.

But in fact, for **original** setting(no any changes on this root path configuration), it is `site\wwwroot`.

If you not modify the **Physical path** value in Azure portal, the `Azure app service deploy task` could not deploy to the path `site\wwwroot`. Because you has been set your customized root path as `site\wwwroot\public`.

[image]

---

In addition, to make path extensible, why not set the default virtual path as `site\wwwroot`, then use one of follow step to achieve the path changed into `site\wwwroot\public`? You know, it's easy to expand the path but difficult to shorten the path level.

**Method 1 to expand the path:**

Specified the value of **Virtual application**:

[image]

Since this is a optional argument, if you did not specified its value, it will deploy the web application to the root path as default.

**Method 2 to expand the path:**

Another way is deploying with folder.

1. Use **Copy file task** to copy the **ZIP** files into `public`
   folder which in the artifacts folder like `.../a/public`.

[image]

2. Specify `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` in the input box **Package
   or folder** of Azuer app service deploy task.

[image]

Now, after the deploy task succeed, you will see that the `ZIP` file is in `public` folder in App service.

Comment: I want it more or less the other way around. I want to deploy in site\wwwroot instead of site\wwwroot\public. I needed to configure this virtual path for my page to work (because index.php is located inside of public, but I also need to update other folders under wwwroot like config and so on).
The newly created app service was just a test to confirm, that the configured virtual path under `Configuration -> Tab Path Mappings` was the cause of the misplaced files.

Comment: @UNeverNo, What about your Virtual directory configuration? Does it is `site\wwwroot\public` or `site\wwwroot`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with `virtual directory configuration`. Are you talking about the app service configuration settings or something in devops?
I did some screenshots to clarify what I'm trying to talk about (see edited initial post).

Comment: @UNeverNo, sorry for not clear mention it. Here I mean the configuration in Azure portal, the first screen shot you provided just now.

Comment: @UNeverNo, I updated my answer according to your details provided. Please check. If still has puzzle, feel free to leave comment.

Comment: If I'd change the path to site\wwwroot my page wouldn't display any longer, because index.php is located in public. So I need to let the virtual path point to that directory. And I want to deploy to site\wwwroot, because I got more folders on the same level as public.

Comment: @UNeverNo, okay, got this trouble. But what about add rules which about index.php page in web.config?

Comment: If I understand you correctly I should change the virtual path to site\wwwroot and add a web.config inside site\wwwroot, that has some rules defined. How would this web.config look like? Can you provide an example or link externally?

Comment: Yeah, correct! See these sample link: https://www.edureka.co/community/6819/how-can-we-rewrite-an-url-in-azure-webapp https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f76fc959-4eee-410a-bb70-f0946127817a/redirect-cname-my-subdomain-azure-subdomain-to-my-site-other-domain?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview and here is our official blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madhurabharadwaj/2018/06/01/azure-app-services-understanding-url-re-write/

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't work out, see my edit above.

Comment: @UNeverNo Soorry for delay reply. I checked your script, it’s all correct just has one problem: you specified the match url as “.*”, you know this means all of http call are all be applied by this rule. That’s why facing the trouble. Here you should use filter expression to filter the pages which should be applied by the rule. Could you show me your file structure? Such as the public file, app source and etc?